# How to organize queries depending on previous queries?

Tags: django

For example I have a ListView that renders some objects, also I have some buttons which use ajax to render these objects with different filters, for example filter by alphabetic order or by some other field. When you use these buttons they return filtered result of ListView objects. If ListView returns objects in published order then buttons will do:

`in published order -> by name -> by views`

How to make the sequence like this:

`in publish order publish -> by name -> by views(by name also) -> by something else(by views also)`

I think that it is possible to hass some vars with ajax request and then depending on this var return another query. But I don't know if it's the best way as I am probably not so good with Django.
So what is the best way for doing this?

Comment: So you have some page with a list of objects and you want to update the `<div>` (for example) with this list with new html when user changes sort order?

Comment: You'll need to include your model and view if you want to get help with the code itself. The basic idea, though, is that you'll send the desired sorting options in your AJAX call, and then use Django's [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) to sort by the items appropriately. `order_by` can take more than one field, so sorting by multiple criteria should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

`app/models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    views = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`app/urls.py` (if you want to try this example, don't forget to include `app.urls` in `project.url`)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

`app/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Entry

def index(request):
    # fields in which we want to order query
    ordering_fields = ['pub_date', 'views', 'title']

    # order_query is field names with dots between them
    order_query = request.GET.get('o')

    # ordering is something like ['views', 'tile']
    ordering = []
    if order_query:
        ordering = [x for x in order_query.split('.') if x in ordering_fields]
    entries = Entry.objects.order_by(*ordering)

    # look at index.html to understand, what query_strings is for
    query_strings = {}
    for field in ordering_fields:
        if field in ordering:
            # remove field
            idx = ordering.index(field)
            query_strings[field] = '.'.join(ordering[:idx]+ordering[idx+1:])
        else:
            # add fieild
            query_strings[field] = '.'.join(ordering + [field])

    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {
        'entries': entries,
        'query_strings': query_strings,
        'ordering': ordering
    })
```

`app/templates/app/index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Entries</title>
  <style>
  table {
    border: 1px solid #333;
  }
  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 5px 10px
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Index</a></p>
  <p>
    Sort by:
    <a href="?o={{ query_strings.title }}">Title</a>{% if 'title' in ordering %}*{% endif %} |
    <a href="?o={{ query_strings.views }}">Views</a>{% if 'views' in ordering %}*{% endif %} |
    <a href="?o={{ query_strings.pub_date }}">Pub date</a>{% if 'pub_date' in ordering %}*{% endif %}
  </p>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Views</th>
        <th>Pub date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entry in entries %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ entry.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.views }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.pub_date }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

URLs for ordering are like these: `?o=title`, `?o=pub_date.views` or `?o=views.title.pub_date`.

In last case result is ordered by `views`, then by `title`, then by `pub_date`. Link for Title is `?o=views.pub_date`, for Views is `?o=views.title` and for Pub date is `o?=views.title`.